Клонирование проекта из репозитория GitLab на Windows ПК (имя папки пользователя на кириллице)
Есть Windows 10 ПК, с пользователем имя которого указано на кириллице, и соответственно папка пользователя (в которой лежит папка .ssh) тоже на кириллице.
Судя по ответу сервера, при выполнении команды git clone ему не нравятся именно кириллические символы в пути до ssh-ключа.
Ответ сервера:
C:\School21\MyProjects>git clone ssh://git@repos-ssh.21-school.ru:2289/students/***************/C3_SimpleBashUtils-1.git
Cloning into 'C3_SimpleBashUtils-1'...
The authenticity of host '[repos-ssh.21-school.ru]:2289 ([178.170.192.137]:2289)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:SPPimLX8PBfuz6bkjwpuOzzt9R0RVyWvSNMf9F2aMK0.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Could not create directory '/c/Users/\300\353\345\352\361\340\355\344\360/.ssh' (No such file or directory).
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/Users/\300\353\345\352\361\340\355\344\360/.ssh/known_hosts).
git@repos-ssh.21-school.ru: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Подскажите, как это можно победить, без переименования папки пользователя. Почитал в Интернете, штатной процедуры переименования папки пользователя в Винде нет, а если делать это руками, то процедура достаточно гиморойная.
Пробовал положить ключи в другую папку, с латинским путем, добавить файл config в штатную папку .ssh пользователя, с указанием пути до ключей, но это тоже не помогло.
Содержание config:
Host repos-ssh.21-school.ru
    HostName repos-ssh.21-school.ru
    User git
    IdentityFile C:\School21\.ssh\id_ed25519

Может что-то здесь неправильно?
В общем, вопрос: Какие есть варианты, решения задачи?

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1704

@user7860670 спасибо за ссылку. Вижу, что не только у меня такая проблема. Почитал с переводчиком, но как решить проблему так и не понял. Обновил OpenSSH и PowerShell, но проблема так и не решена. Если Вы знаете, как ее решить, подскажите пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен.
